# How to convert an Ethernet interface (via USB) to a simple RJ45

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, adapter, rj-45

I have a device that outputs a USB cable that, when plugged into a computer, creates it’s own network interface.

My question is, how can I convert that USB cable to a RJ45 Ethernet cable, so that I can plug it in a switch and make other computers capable of connecting to that device?

Comment: A USB endpoint is either a USB host or a USB gadget.  So your *"device"* that plugs into the USB port of a computer must be a USB gadget (aka USB slave device) because PCs almost exclusively have only USB host (type A connector) ports and rarely have gadget ports.  So the only way to *"convert that USB cable to a RJ45 Ethernet"* port is to use an intermediate USB host, which requires at least a SBC (single board computer), e.g. a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If that device creates a kind of “full-featured” interface, you can bridge that interface to a physical one, so people on your network will be able to access it.

If you need this to be autonomous, you can, as @sawdust suggested, set the bridge on a separate mini-PC, like Raspberry Pi.

The third possibility is that *that* device of yours actually has Ethernet interface inside, but it is either not available as an output port (only the holes on PCB, that require soldering), or it already has (the most simple, although not very likely case) an ethernet-USB converter inside for some weird reason.

Comment: Pardon my incomprehension but if by "bridge that interface to a physical one" you mean a switch, how can I do this since it's basically a USB cable? Also, the device does not possess an ethernet port (at least visible), the chips contained in the circuit are even "grayed out" by the manufacturer so I can't identify them.

Comment: @Lawris, I mean not a physical switch, but software bridging, something like this: https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/bridge-network-connections-in-windows-7-8-10/ or this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee126153(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN